# Error is returned while using getURL() function in R language

Tags: r

i have started learning data science and new to R language, 
i am trying to read data from below *HTTPS URL using getURL funtion and Rcurl pacakge.*

while executing below code, receiving `SSL` protocal issue.

## R Code

## load the library Rcurl

library(RCurl)

## specify the URL for the Iris data CSV

```
urlfile = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data'
```

## download the file

```
downloaded = getURL(urlfile, ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)
```

Error

> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :    Unknown SSL
>   protocol error in connection to archive.ics.uci.edu:443

can anyone help me with this answer?

Answer (score 3):

First see if you can read data from the URL with:

fileURL <- "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data"
myfile <- readLines(fileURL)
head(myfile)

If you can read data from the URL, then the embedded double quotes in the data may be causing your problem.
Try read.csv with the quote parameter:

```
iris <- read.csv(fileURL, header = FALSE, sep = ",", quote = "\"'")
names(iris) <- c("sepal_length", "sepal_width", "petal_length", "petal_width", "class")
head(iris)
```

Comment: Sorry, the newlines in my post did not work correctly.